# PC sometimes turns on and sometimes not with different outlets

Tags: boot, power-supply, voltage, start

When the Pc is plugged to an outlet and I press the on button, it will sometimes turn on. when the pc is on and goes into sleep mode, it won’t turn back on again. I tried replugging the cord to same outlet and sometimes it will turn on after waiting but sometimes it wont turn on at all

I tried plugging the pc in different outlets in the same room but PC still shows the same effect. the PC will turn on but after it goes to sleep mode, it cannot turn back on.

I’m not sure if the PSU is just highly sensitive to voltage differences in the outlets or if there is damaged components in the PC

Appreciate any thoughts and ideas on what’s wrong with the PC

Comment: It is unclear from your question whether changing the mains outlet has *any* effect. Could you please edit the question to make that clear? Was any outlet *consistently* better or worse than another??

Comment: Some outlets working better than others would suggest there's something wrong with your outlets. Voltage differences are too small to matter under normal circumstances.